# Is pacific tycoon a legitimate company?

Tags: hong-kong, shipping

I keep seeing advertisements for pacific tycoon on youtube - they're looking for people to buy shipping containers, and lease them back, or some variation on that theme.

Are pacific tycoon a legitimate company? Can they be trusted to do what they're promising to do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

The company may be real though the returns do have some fine print to note.

[Pacific Tycoon – Investor Red Alert](http://tomwinnifrith.com/articles/2675/pacific-tycoon-investor-red-alert) notes in part:

> I see that some unscrupulous financial websites are taking money to
>   send out promotions today for Pacific Tycoon. DO NOT RESPOND. DO NOT
>   INVEST. You are being treated with utter contempt as a reader of these
>   sites and should unsubscribe at once. And here is why.

While some people may be happy with them, that isn't the same as someone that wants more assurances as to the returns on their money.